# Injection of multiple BrowserModules in Angular yet only one in my code

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering whether it is possible that Angular injects its own browsermodule without us having to do so? This is because I am learning standalone components where I have decided to make my root component (The App Component) a standalone component, therefore, I am bootstrapping it in `main.ts`. I keep on getting an error that I am injecting more than 1 browsermodule in my application, and I suspect it is coming from `main.ts`. Now, I will provide my the TS file for my App Component and my `main.ts`. Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

Any concerns, please let me know

main.ts:

```js
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent)
```

App Component TS:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, // only 1 but still displays error?
    AppRoutingModule, // a root router module where there are 0 routes so far
    ListComponent, // a standalone component
  ],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bootstrapApplication` function that is used for bootstrapping standalone applications comes from `@angular/platform-browser`, and, if we [take a look at what it does](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5bd188a394d30053099e2c83fe79136d590e5399/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L94) we can see that it adds the following providers:

```
return {
  appProviders: [
    ...BROWSER_MODULE_PROVIDERS,
    ...(options?.providers ?? []),
  ],
  platformProviders: INTERNAL_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS
};
```

If we compare this to what `BrowserModule` [provides](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5bd188a394d30053099e2c83fe79136d590e5399/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L229) we can see that it is pretty much the same thing:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [...BROWSER_MODULE_PROVIDERS, ...TESTABILITY_PROVIDERS],
  exports: [CommonModule, ApplicationModule],
})
export class BrowserModule {
  /* ... */
}
```

So, you don't need to provide BrowserModule anywhere in your app as long as you use `bootstrapApplication`.

Comment: well it worked! but only after I removed the routing module, which again was injected more than once. So I suppose bootstrapApplication provides a `RouterModule.forRoot()` already right?

Comment: [provideRouter](https://angular.io/api/router/provideRouter) is a functional equivalent of Module-based `RouterModule.forRoot()` so only one of them should be used. I guess you had the former one :)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually importing `BrowserModule`.

When you run the **`bootstrapApplication`** method, **`BrowserModule`** is provided under the hood.

[You can check these comments from source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5bd188a394d30053099e2c83fe79136d590e5399/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L172-L177)